# What checks should I go through if my laptop can't connect to the internet through tethering?

Tags: tethering, wifi-tethering, usb-tethering

I need to connect my laptop to the Internet by tethering through my smartphone, I'm using a Galaxy GT-S7270 with Android 4.2.2, a laptop with Windows 7 and a tablet with Windows 8.

---

Whenever I try to use the WIFI hotspot, while I can connect and access the internet with my tablet the laptop gets a limited access after connecting to the smartphone.

This behavior stays the same of I try to tether form another device, like for example my roommate's I-Phone or a WIFI signal coming from it laptop through a certain software (which in fact doesn't work for my tablet either).

---

If I try to use USB tether, as soon as I activate it from the menu in Android, the file manager of Windows doesn't list my device anymore, if I deactivate the USB tether the device is listed again.

This happens for both MTP and PNP protocols, in addition the PTP protocol trigger a warning saying that there are problems with the drivers of the dev
ice.

---

The laptop doesn't have a Bluetooth transmitter.

---

I won't have access to any other access point but the smartphone for a while, what can I do to connect my laptop to the internet?

---

EDIT: I had success downloading some unofficial drivers from the Internet and using them to make a USB tether.

Still, the same drivers don't work on the tablet and the whole process has been a series of random attempts.

Since I still don't have a "method" and the reasons of a certain connection working on a certain device and others not working, I will leave the question here.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "the laptop gets a limited access."

Comment: @Joe Sewell I mean that even if the connection itself is established the laptop doesn't have access to the internet, in Windows words this is flagged "limited access" and happens either when further authentication is needed with the network or possibly the network itself is not connected to the Internet.

Comment: Ah. Not familiar with what MeSs-Windows means in that context. To me it connects or it doesn't.

Comment: It's something like "I'm connected to device X, but device X is not connected to the internet" where X can be a smartphone, router, etc. I don't really know the details either, I guess it checks for some kind of response on a ping check or something..

Comment: Did you modify the windows laptop hosts file, and replaced it with a big adblock hosts file?

Answer (score 0):

Having a limited connection is a common issue in Windows 7/8/10. The only good method I've seen that works is doing a system restore to a earlier restore point (not a full wipe of the laptop). It'll be under Backup and Restore in Control Panel. Every time Windows updates it creates a backup which you'll want to use to undo any issues that may have caused the limited WiFi bug.